# Ajax File Upload storing bytes until save java.

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload

I'm a java developer using Tapestry5. I'm using a jQuery plugin to manage my file uploads via ajax.

I'm looking for the best approach to temporarily saving the attachments until the actual page has been saved. My current work flow consist of a user uploading / removing a file with either the ajax upload box or an ajax remove link positioned next to the file like gmail attachments. I do not want to commit the file to the database until after the file has been uploaded and the save action within the form has been clicked.

I'm currently uploading the files and saving them to the user session until the save action within the form has been clicked. This works perfectly fine providing only one tab is in use, however I'm not sure that is the best approach.

Does anybody have any additional suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to do something somewhat similar, but, with a slightly different stack (ASP.NET MVC).

The way I solved the problem was by generating a GUID on the page load and stuffing it inside of a hidden input.  Your data store could be whatever you want (session, database, disk, etc - just be sure to include the GUID as part of your key).  When the user saves the form just be sure to include your hidden input data and then you will have a unique way of identifying the files that were part of that instance.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I would end up needing to store a GUID with the attachment to prevent cross tab issues, but I just wasn't sure if storing the attachments in the user session was the best idea do to the potential size and effect that could have on the system memory over multiple users.

Comment: @George - That's a completely fair question, but, I can't answer that.  It depends on the possible size of files and the estimated number of files you would have to hold in memory at a given time.  I personally used disk for my temporary storage as I didn't want to fill up memory.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing so far seems right, and you are also right that you could run into trouble if the user attempts to use your web app within multiple tabs. What you could do is :

1. Obtain a unique key before any file is uploaded with an ajax call. (note: as user @Ek0nomik suggests, this could also be included in a hidden input property when generating the page)
2. Whenever a file is uploaded, make sure to also submit this key.
3. When the form is saved, the key is submitted, you then know which files should be committed in the database.

Comment: Is it best to store the attachments in memory or write to disk until your ready to make a database commit?

Comment: I would store them on the disk, with a batch running periodically to remove left-over files.